# Алгоритм выбора строки по его приоритету

Tags: алгоритм, статистика

Есть 10 человек и у каждого есть приоритет на получение конфет.  У нас есть 10 конфет которые мы в зависимости от приоритета должны поделить.

```
Пользователь |   приоритет | мест в кармане
user1            40%           2
user2            50%           3
user3            10%           2
user4             0%           2
user5             0%           1
user6             0%           2
user7             0%           3 
user8             0%           4
user9             0%           1 
user10            0%           2
```

1. Первые 7 конфет распределяются между `user1, user2, user3` так как у них приоритет > 0. Остальные - между остальными.
2. Остальные 3 конфеты случайно выпадают `user4-user10`

Так как цифры небольшие, то можно ручками посчитать. Но хотелось бы привести это в алгоритм. Это не просто делёжка конфет. Розыгрыш.

Comment: По моему скромному мнению, этот вопрос не соответствует правилам. Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос то, какие собственные попытки были сделаны и что за конкретные трудности встретились на пути?

Comment: То есть вы просите составить вам точный алгоритм, по тому алгоритму, который вы расплывчато описали словами? Тут сложно дать однозначный ответ и определить критерии его "правильности" ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм простой

1. Создаем и заполняем map списков key =priority, value = list мест в кармане.
2. Для каждого элемента map в порядке убывания priority. Раздать случайно конфеты  (не имеет значения даже если всем достанется)
3. Если конфеты остались повторят шаг 2
4. вывести результат

Если приоритеты равны то случайно выбираете поскольку при одинаковых приоритетах

Answer (score 1):

Делаем объект с полями юзер, приоритет, мест в кармане. Заполняем список из этих объектов. Сортируем по приоритету, выдаем конфеты по условию приоритет > 0, выдаем остальным по рандому.